# Racket List Questio

Tags: racket

Does anyone know how to return a number of specific elements in a list?

Example: given

```
(list 'a 'a 'a 'a 'a 'b 'b 'b)
```

Returns the numbers of `'a:` 5

numbers of `'b:` 3

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: combine length and filter

Comment: I somewhat managed to find out how haha

Answer (score 1):

You count them. You make a procedure that takes a list and what you want to search for and you iterate that list while keeping a count and when you reach the end you return that value.

A skeleton for a simple recursive solution:

```
(define (count-element element lst)
  (define (helper lst count)
    (cond ((empty? lst) count)
          ((equal? element <first element>) <recurse whith cdr and increasing count>)
          (else <recurse with cdr>)))
  (helper lst 0))
```

Or you can use `foldl`

```
(define (count-element element lst)
  (foldl (lambda (e count)
           (if <e is the same as element>
               <return 1 more than count>
               <return count>))
         0
         lst))
```

There are probably 10 more ways I could do it, but the first is the most educational and the second the most common way I would do it.
Some tests:

```
(define test '(a a a a a b b b))

(count-element 'b '()) ; ==> 0
(count-element 'e test) ; ==> 0 
(count-element 'a test) ; ==> 5
(count-element 'b test) ; ==> 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I haven't used `count` yet, but I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: @Jason `count` is just a variable holding the current number of matches. It makes the procedure more efficient than if I did it like in your supplied answer.

Comment: Thanks!, I'll try that with another version

Answer (score 1):

I somewhat managed to find the answer, so here's the function definition:

```
(define (number-of s L)
  (cond
    [(empty? L) 0]
    [else (cond [(eq? s (first L)) (+ 1 (number-of s (rest L)))]
                [else (number-of s (rest L))])]))
```

Comment: Whole point of `cond` is that you have multiple terms while `if` only has one and needs nesting. Both `cond` can be squashed together as one leaving more readable code.

Comment: I'm still in the basics of this language so I haven't known about it, but I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: some prefer `cond` over `if` always, since with the `cond` each clause's condition is right there, but `if` is positional, so, forces *us* to remember. cf. [Boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/).